How to see if one value if found anywhere else
I have two columns, one of 12599 5 letter combinations and one with 14854 accepted wordle guesses. Is there any way I could check a 5 letter combination against all of the accepted wordle words and have it give me an answer yes or no if that combination shows up it the accepted wordle words, and be able to do this for all 12599 5 letter combinations?

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please [edit] your question and add a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

Use countif(), like this:
=arrayformula(ifs( 
  isblank(B2:B), iferror(ø), 
  countif(A2:A, B2:B), "Yes", 
  true, "No" 
))


See countif().
